# For loop vs. Iterator to avoid ConcurrentModificationException with an ArrayList

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, concurrency, thread-safety

**Question**: What is the optimal (performance-wise) solution for the add, removal, modification of items within an ArrayList which at the same time avoids the `ConcurrentModificationException` from being thrown during operations?

**Context**: Based on my research looking into this question, there doesn't seem to be any straight-forward answers to the question at hand - most recommend using `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, but my understanding is that it is *not recommended* for array lists of large size (which I am working with, hence the performance-aspect of the question).

Thus, my understanding can be summarized as the following, but want to make sure if is correct/incorrect:

**IMPORTANT NOTE: The following statements all assume that the operation is done within a synchronized block.**

- **Remove** during iteration of an `ArrayList` should be done with an `Iterator`, because for loop results in unpredictable behavior if removal is done within the middle of a collection. Example:

```
Iterator<Item> itemIterator = items.iterator();
while (itemIterator.hasNext()) {
  Item item = itemIterator.next();
  // check if item needs to be removed
  itemIterator.remove();
}
```

- For **add** operations, cannot be done with an `Iterator`, but can be with `ListIterator`. Example:

```
ListIterator<Item> itemIterator = list.listIterator();
while(itemIterator.hasNext()){
  \\ do some operation which requires iteration of the ArrayList
  itemIterator.add(item);                
}
```

- For **add** operations, a `ListIterator` does NOT have to be necessarily be used (i.e. simply `items.add(item)` should not cause any problems).
- For **add** operations while going through the collection can be done with EITHER a `ListIterator` or a for loop, but NOT an `Iterator`. Example:

```
Iterator<Item> itemIterator = item.iterator();
while (itemIterator.hasNext()) {
  \\ do some operation which requires iteration of the ArrayList
  items.add(item); \\ NOT acceptable - cannot modify ArrayList while in an Iterator of that ArrayList
}
```

- **Modification** of an item within an ArrayList can be done with either an `Iterator` or a for loop with the same performance complexity (*is this true?*). Example:

```
\\ iterator example

Iterator<Item> itemIterator = item.iterator();
while (itemIterator.hasNext()) {
  Item item = itemIterator.next();
  item.update(); // modifies the item within the ArrayList during iteration
}

\\ for loop example

for (Item item : items){
  item.update();
}
```

Will modification during iteration with the `Iterator` have the same performance as the for loop? Are there any thread-safety differences between the approaches?

**Bonus question:** what advantage does using a `synchronizedList` of the ArrayList for add/remove/modify operations vs. for loop vs. iterator if it also requires a synchronized block?

Comment: The `for` loop effectively creates and uses an `Iterator`. You'll get the same exception if you allow the list to be modified while the loop is in-progress.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between `while` loops and `for` loops and in fact, the idiomatic form of a loop using an iterator explicitly, is a `for` loop:

```java
for(Iterator<Item> it = items.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    Item item = it.next();
    item.update();
}
```

which gets compiled to exactly the same code as

```java
for(Item item: items) {
  item.update();
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVPRToMwFH3nK254gmTrBzjdy6KJiZol@mZ8qLQbdwJt2gvTLHw7tjAmG0tcYuxDoT3nnt5zKBte8elGfDQN5loZgo3bYCVhxu5JGk7KzIIR9ICWzmxbjexFqWxpVIVCusogybi18MixgF0AbujyPcMELHFyj0qhgNyh0TMZLNavb8DN2sZ7sh82VduFyjVmUiyUkFE8a7E66PQMVpzkkeC4ZKA3bJCtsBB3aCxFobehw5jhammklQVFpGE6B9LMlK6/L0syZ6qkCezfpTETCKdJ6GbvMIxPWhtbXSnTxxr5EK/dKp8DuvnItONFPfHAgZuOyLCXiGduh6XcPslP8quhhh@@tC1qa1nR0Y4oHmWlFi7EIVT/7uSWJ@klLroOrsb4H47fpu7jXhTlRTEe2K1uNAz1nyLdm@n@j1bz55jWYV8Pu/rcffcXrgPrpvkG)

There are no performance differences for identical compiled code dependent to the original source code used to produce it.

---

Instead of focusing on the loop form, you have to focus on the fundamental limitations when inserting or removing elements of an `ArrayList`. Each time you insert or remove an element, the elements behind the affected index have to be copied to a new location. This isn’t very expensive, as the array only consists of *references* to the objects, but the costs can easily add up when doing it repeatedly.

So, if you know that the number of insertions or removals is predictably small or will happen at the end or close to the end (so there is only a small number of elements to copy), it’s not a problem. But when inserting or removing an arbitrary number of elements at arbitrary positions in a loop, you run into a *quadratic time complexity*.

You can avoid this, by using

```java
items.removeIf(item -> /* check and return whether to remove the item*/);
```

This will use an internal iteration and postpone the moving of elements until their final position is known, leading to a *linear time complexity*.

If that’s not feasible, you might be better off copying the list into a new list, skipping the unwanted elements. This will be slightly less efficient but still have a linear time complexity. That’s also the solution for inserting a significant number of items at arbitrary positions.

---

The `item.update();` in an entirely different category. “the item within the ArrayList” is a wrong mindset. As said above, the `ArrayList` contains *references* to objects whereas the object itself is not affected by “being inside the ArrayList”. In fact, objects can be in multiple collections at the same time, as all standard collections only contain references.

So `item.update();` changes the `Item` object, which is an operation independent of the `ArrayList`, which is dangerous when you assume a thread safety based on the list.

When you have code like

```java
Item item = items.get(someIndex);
// followed by using item
```

<sup>where `get` is from a `synchronizedList`</sup>

or a manually synchronized retrieval operation which returns the item to the caller or any other form of code which uses a retrieved `Item` *outside* the `synchronized` block,

then *your code is not thread safe*. It doesn’t help when the `update()` call is done under a synchronization or lock when looping over the list, when the other uses are outside the synchronization or lock. To be thread safe, all uses of an object must be protected by the same thread safety construct.

---

So even when you use the `synchronizedList`, you must not only guard your loops manually, [as the documentation already tells](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)), you also have to expand the protection to all other uses of the contained elements, if they are mutable.

Alternatively, you could have different mechanisms for the list and the contained elements, if you know what you are doing, but it still means that the simplicity of “just wrap the list with `synchronizedList`” isn’t there.

So what advantage does it have? Actually none. It might have helped developers during the migration from Java 1.1 and its all-synchronized `Vector` and `Hashtable` to Java 2’s Collection API. But I never had a use for the synchronized wrappers at all. Any nontrivial use case requires manual synchronization (or locking) anyway.